# Analysis of SharePoint servers connectivity

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, 2019, farm, services

I need a tool or solution which can discover all connections between SharePoint 2019 farm servers.

So I can discover what services is running and what is making very high load on server processor and what is sending many request to server.

As we used SharePoint as public internet website.